# Get concurrent user's avatar in SignalR chat

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

This is the ChatHub code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;

namespace BIX
{
    public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        static ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> dic = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();
        public void Send(string name, string message)
        {
            Clients.All.broadcastMessage(name, message);
        }

        public void SendToSpecific(string name, string message, string to)
        {
            Clients.Caller.broadcastMessage(name, message);
            Clients.Client(dic[to]).broadcastMessage(name, message);
        }

        public void Notify(string name, string id)
        {
            if (dic.ContainsKey(name))
            {
                Clients.Caller.differentName();
            }
            else
            {
                dic.TryAdd(name, id);
                foreach (KeyValuePair<String, String> entry in dic)
                {
                    Clients.Caller.online(entry.Key);
                }
                Clients.Others.enters(name);
            }
        }

        public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
        {
            var name = dic.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == Context.ConnectionId.ToString());
            string s;
            dic.TryRemove(name.Key, out s);
            return Clients.All.disconnected(name.Key);
        }  
    }
}
```

It run well, but the problem is it only can pass correct username and message between other chatters , if I use the user's avatar url then only we cannot get the right avatar. So my question is how to use the ConcurrentDictionary to pass one more key (avatar's url) instead of only one Tkey and one TValue. 
Please see my picture :

> Chat UI 1

[image]

> Chat UI2

[image]

You can see my chat app can pass correct message , but it displayed wrong avatar. Please help!

And this is the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {
        startChatHub();
    });
    var nickname = "";
    var avatarurl = "";

    function startChatHub() {
        var chat = $.connection.chatHub;

        // Get the user name.
        nickname = "<%= userName %>";
        avatarurl = "<%= userImage %>";

        chat.client.online = function(name) {
            // Update list of users  
            if (name == nickname) {
                $("#chat_body").append("<img src=" + avatarurl + " class=\"avatar\" /><div id=\"userlist\">" + name + "</div>");
                $("#msg_head").append("<div id=userchat>" + name + "</div>");

            } else {
                $("#chat_body").append("<img src=" + avatarurl + " class=\"avatar\" /><div id=\"userlist\">" + name + "</div>");
                $("#users").append("<option value=\"" + name + "\">" + name + "</option>");
            }
        };
        chat.client.enters = function(name) {
            $("#msg_body").append("<div ><i>" + name + " joins the conversation</i></div>");
            $("#users").append("<option value=\"" + name + "\">" + name + "</option>");
            //$("#chat_body").append("<div id=userlist>" + name + "</div>");
            $("#chat_body").append("<img src=" + avatarurl + " class=\"avatar\" /><div id=\"userlist\">" + name + "</div>");
        };
        // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast chat messages.  
        chat.client.broadcastMessage = function(name, message) {
            //Interpret smileys  
            message = message.replace(":)", "<img src=\"/ChatJS/Images/Emoticons/smile-2.png\" class=\"smileys\" />");
            message = message.replace(":D", "<img src=\"/ChatJS/Images/Emoticons/smile-1.png\" />");
            message = message.replace(":o", "<img src=\"/ChatJS/Images/Emoticons/smile-6.png\" />");

            //display the message  
            //$("#msg_body").append("<div class=\"border\"><span style=\"color:orange\">" + name + "</span>: " + message + "</div>");
            $("#msg_body").append("<img src=" + avatarurl + " class=\"avatar\" />", message);
        };

        chat.client.disconnected = function(name) {
            //Calls when someone leaves the page  
            $("#msg_body").append("<div ><i>" + name + " leaves the conversation</i></div>");
            $("#chat_body div").remove(":contains('" + name + "')");
            jQuery(this).attr("src", "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///////yH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==");
            $("#users option").remove(":contains('" + name + "')");
        };
        //scroll bar
        $(".chat_head").click(function() {
            $("#chat_body").slideToggle("slow");
        });
        $("#msg_head").click(function() {
            $(".msg_wrap").slideToggle("slow");
        });

        $(".close").click(function() {
            $(".msg_box").hide();
        });

        $("#userlist").click(function() {

            $(".msg_wrap").show();
            $(".msg_box").show();
        });

        // Start the connection.  
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function() {
            //Calls the notify method of the server  
            chat.server.notify(nickname, $.connection.hub.id);
            $("#messagebox").keypress(function(e) {
                if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                    var msg = "<div id=msg_b>" + $("#messagebox").val() + "</div>";
                    $("#messagebox").val("");
                    if ($("#users").val() == "All") {
                        //Call the Send method on the hub.  
                        chat.server.send(nickname, msg);
                        $("#msg_body").scrollTop($("#msg_body")[0].scrollHeight);
                    } else {
                        chat.server.sendToSpecific(nickname, msg, $("#users").val());
                        //Clear text box and reset focus for next comment.   
                        $("#messagebox").val("").focus();
                        $("#msg_body").scrollTop($("#msg_body")[0].scrollHeight);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: perhaps you need to track and or get the Avatar's ID can you pinpoint the issue by debugging your code..?

Comment: Debug my code and see that it get the current avatar user's session url. So it only can display the current user's avatar because in the ChatHub, i use the ConcurrentDictionary<Tkey,TValue>. So we only can pass (name, message) . We cannot pass one more value! The the reason why I  need another solution for this

Comment: Any reason the dictionary can't use a POCO instead of `string` for the value - `ConcurrentDictionary<string, SomeClassThatHasNamePlusAvatar>`?

Comment: @Brendan Green. Could you explain more detail about POCO. I get the username and user's avatar from login session

Comment: And one thing I want to ask is: if I put SignalR code in a separated aspx page. It works, but when I put it in the Masterpage that also include all necessary reference. It cannot work. I cannot find out the problem. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Came across this when looking for .netCore 6 solution with Blazor. Since I didn't find one I created one. Images are stored as bytes[] in SQL server AspNetUsers table. This is an extension of a Github project you can find here : https://github.com/enetstudio/SignalRServerIdentityAuthentication

1. Create a service to query the usermanager.

```
public class UserProfileService
{
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    private readonly AuthenticationStateProvider _authenticationStateProvider;

    public byte[] UserPicture { get; set; }

    public UserProfileService(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, AuthenticationStateProvider authenticationStateProvider)
    {
    _authenticationStateProvider = authenticationStateProvider;
    _userManager = userManager;
    }
    public async Task GetProfilePicture()
    {
        try
        {
             var authState = await _authenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
             var user = authState.User;
             var currentUser = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(user);
             UserPicture = currentUser.ProfilePicture;
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             Debug.WriteLine("Exception Message: " + ex.Message);
         }
    }
```

Add it as a scoped service in startup.cs

```
services.AddScoped<UserProfileService>();
```

2. Create a dictionary to hold user name and string representation of image bytes[]

```
public class ProfileMapping<T>
    {
        private readonly Dictionary<T, HashSet<string>> _profiles = new Dictionary<T, HashSet<string>>();

        public int Count
        {
            get
            {
                return _profiles.Count;
            }
        }

        public void Add(T key, string Avatar)
        {
            lock (_profiles)
            {
                HashSet<string> avatars;
                if (!_profiles.TryGetValue(key, out avatars))
                {
                    avatars = new HashSet<string>();
                    _profiles.Add(key, avatars);
                }

                lock (avatars)
                {
                    avatars.Add(Avatar);
                }
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable<string> GetAvatar(T key)
        {
            HashSet<string> avatars;
            if (_profiles.TryGetValue(key, out avatars))
            {
                return avatars;
            }

            return Enumerable.Empty<string>();
        }

        public IEnumerable<T> GetUsers()
        {
            return _profiles.Keys.ToList<T>();
        }

        public void Remove(T key, string Avatar)
        {
            lock (_profiles)
            {
                HashSet<string> avatars;
                if (!_profiles.TryGetValue(key, out avatars))
                {
                    return;
                }

                lock (avatars)
                {
                    avatars.Remove(Avatar);

                    if (avatars.Count == 0)
                    {
                        _profiles.Remove(key);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Inject it in the chat.razor component

```
@inject UserProfileService _profileService
```

Initialise it in the chat.razor.cs class.

```
private readonly static ProfileMapping<string> _profiles = new ProfileMapping<string>();
private byte[] _data;
```

Add/remove user and avatar to/from the dictionary

```
private async Task OpenForm()
{
    var profile = _profileService.GetProfilePicture();
    string Avatar = Convert.ToBase64String(_profileService.UserPicture);
    _profiles.Add(userName, Avatar);
    await module.InvokeVoidAsync("openForm").AsTask();
}

private async Task CloseForm()
{
    var profile = _profileService.GetProfilePicture();
    string Avatar = Convert.ToBase64String(_profileService.UserPicture);
    _profiles.Remove(userName, Avatar);
    await module.InvokeVoidAsync("closeForm").AsTask();
}
```

Then grab it in the Chat.razor component

```
@foreach (var message in messages)
{
    string Sender = message.Before(":");
    string messagecontent = message.After(":");
    var list = _profiles.GetAvatar(Sender);
    foreach (var profile in list)
    {
        _data = Convert.FromBase64String(profile);
    }
    <div class="d-flex align-items-center text-right justify-content-end ">
      <div class="pr-2">
        <span class="name">@Sender</span>
         <p class="msg">@messagecontent</p>
     </div>
      <div><img src="data:image/*;base64,@(Convert.ToBase64String(_data))" width="30" class="img1" />
     </div>
   </div>
}
```

where the hubconnection receive is defined as:

```
hubConnection.On<string, string>("ReceiveMessage", async (user, message) =>
{                    
    var encodedMsg = $"{user}:{message}";
    messages.Add(encodedMsg);
    await InvokeAsync(() => StateHasChanged());
});
```

Hope this helps someone.